# How to make posts_like_dislike reference current post when iterating?

Tags: php, posts, wp-query, get-posts

I am using plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-like-dislike/ . It adds a `[posts_like_dislike]` shortcode. When inside the default wordpress Twenty Twenty-Three in posts "Blog Home" view [in here](https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwentythree/blob/11440a5b38bae6882fc2c00b703d4bb95420a0f5/templates/home.html#L11):

```
<!-- wp:query {"queryId":0,"query":{"pages":0,"offset":0,"postType":"post","order":"desc","orderBy":"date","author":"","search":"","exclude":[],"sticky":"","inherit":true,"perPage":10},"align":"wide","layout":{"type":"constrained"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-query alignwide"><!-- wp:post-template {"align":"wide","layout":{"type":"default","columnCount":3}} -->
<!-- wp:columns -->
<!-- wp:column -->
<!-- wp:shortcode -->
[posts_like_dislike]
<!-- /wp:shortcode -->
<!-- /wp:column -->
<!-- /wp:columns -->
<!-- /wp:query -->
```

It "works", but it always references the *first* post. It is because `$post` global variable inside some `wp:query` is set to the first post.

[This is](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/posts-like-dislike/trunk/inc/views/frontend/like-dislike-html.php#L2) how the plugin gets the post id. In comparison, the `core/` blocks use [this code](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/post-comments-count/index.php#L16) that they receive a `$block` parameter to `WP_Block` from `render_callback` from `register_block_type_from_metadata`.

How can I access current post ID from inside a shortcode inside wp:query? How can I access current `WP_Block $block` from inside shortcode or from php? Is there anything else I can try?

I tried doing a lot of research, I tried `<?php echo(get_the_ID()); echo(get_post())` but it all references `$post` which is always the first post only. What is not right?